# How to stop printing few particular lines in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script for minimising chi2 function.
When I run the script it prints me a long lines of "J2000.0" and then gives the value of my calculation. I know these successive lines of "J2000.0" comes because of my determination of astrophysical coordinate system.

Now, I just want to get rid of printing the lines "J2000.0".
I tried the piece of code following:

```
import sys, os

# Disable
def blockPrint():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

# Restore
def enablePrint():
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__



blockPrint()
```

But it blocks even later on outputs which I want to read.
Can anyone please help me with a code which will help not to show only the lines containing "J2000.0"?

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the wrong point. Your script for minimising is the one that is at fault, because it is printing out the values. Surely it should not have printing inside it, and should return a result, which you can then choose to print or use.

Comment: Despite its name, `python-requests` has nothing to do with "requesting help for Python". Please make sure to read tag descriptions before using them.

Comment: Please remove the numpy and python-requests tag. It does not seem like you use either library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some interpreters (like jupyter notebook) do not print on the console by default. So if you call `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` you force printing to the console instead of the browser.

The belows code works for me.

```
import sys, os

class HandlePrint():

    def __init__(self):
        self.initial_stout = sys.stdout

    def blockPrint(self):
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

    # Restore
    def resetPrint(self):
        sys.stdout = self.initial_stout

handle = HandlePrint()
handle.blockPrint()

print 'AAAA'

handle.resetPrint()
print 'BBBB'
```